# Filter file to list all paths in it

Tags: text-processing, filenames

How can I filter text file to remove every thing and just leave the paths in it?
For example:

```
dslkjcblasdjncklasdnlc /asdds/ads/adss/sdf.jpg asljdascuashn sdkm
/sdf/dsf/dsf/dfs/sdfs.txt ,nbaskhdnasm.ddslkjcblasdjncklasdnlc
/asdds/ads/adss/sdf.jpg asljdascuashn sdkm /sdf/dsf/dsf/dfs/sdfs.txt
,nbaskhdnasm.ddslkjcblasdjncklasdnlc /asdds/ads/adss/sdf.jpg
 asljdascuashn sdkm /34/34/dsf/dfs/sdfs.txt
 ,nbaskhdnasm.ddslkjcblasdjncklasdnlc /asdds/ads/adss/sdf.jpg
 asljdascuashn sdkm /sdf/dsf/dsf/dfs/sdfs.txt
 ,nbaskhdnasm.ddslkjcblasdjncklasdnlc /sd/df/fg/fgsdf.jpg asljdascuashn
 sdkm /sdf/dsf/34/dfs/sdfs.txt ,nbaskhdnasm.ddslkjcblasdjncklasdnlc
 /asdds/ads/adss/sdf.jpg asljdascuashn sdkm /sdf/dsf/dsf/dfs/sdfs.txt
 ,nbaskhdnasm.ddslkjcblasdjncklasdnlc /qw2/sd23/adss/sdf.jpg
 asljdascuashn sdkm /34/34/dsf/dfs/sdfs.png
 ,nbaskhdnasm.ddslkjcblasdjncklasdnlc /asdds/ads/adss/sdf.jpg
 asljdascuashn sdkm /sdf/dsf/dsf/dfs/sdfs.txt
 ,nbaskhdnasm.ddslkjcblasdjncklasdnlc /wre/ads/adss/sdf.nii
 asljdascuashn sdkm /sdf/dsf34/dsf/dfs/sdfs.pmb
 ,nbaskhdnasm.ddslkjcblasdjncklasdnlc /asdds/ads/adss/sdf.jpg
 asljdascuashn sdkm /sdf/dsf/dsf/dfs/sdfs.txt
 ,nbaskhdnasm.ddslkjcblasdjncklasdnlc /34/ads/34/sdf.jpg asljdascuashn
 sdkm /34/dsf/dsf/34/sdfs.dbt ,nbaskhdnasm.ddslkjcblasdjncklasdnlc
 /asdds/ads/adss/sdf.jpg asljdascuashn sdkm /sdf/dsf/dsf/dfs/sdfs.txt
 ,nbaskhdnasm.ddslkjcblasdjncklasdnlc /34/34/34/sdf.zip asljdascuashn
 sdkm /sd34f/dsf/dsf/34/sdfs.tar.gz ,nbaskhdnasm.d
```

how can i remove everything and leave only the paths so I get:

```
/asdds/ads/adss/sdf.jpg 
/sdf/dsf/dsf/dfs/sdfs.txt 
/asdds/ads/adss/sdf.jpg 
/sdf/dsf/dsf/dfs/sdfs.txt 
/asdds/ads/adss/sdf.jpg 
/34/34/dsf/dfs/sdfs.txt 
/ads/adss/sdf.jpg 
/sdf/dsf/dsf/dfs/sdfs.txt 
/sd/df/fg/fgsdf.jpg 
/sdf/dsf/34/dfs/sdfs.txt 
/asdds/ads/adss/sdf.jpg 
/sdf/dsf/dsf/dfs/sdfs.txt 
/qw2/sd23/adss/sdf.jpg 
/34/34/dsf/dfs/sdfs.png
/asdds/ads/adss/sdf.jpg 
/sdf/dsf/dsf/dfs/sdfs.txt 
/wre/ads/adss/sdf.nii 
/sdf/dsf34/dsf/dfs/sdfs.pmb 
/asdds/ads/adss/sdf.jpg 
/sdf/dsf/dsf/dfs/sdfs.txt 
/34/ads/34/sdf.jpg
/34/dsf/dsf/34/sdfs.dbt
/asdds/ads/adss/sdf.jpg 
/sdf/dsf/dsf/dfs/sdfs.txt 
/34/34/34/sdf.zip 
/sd34f/dsf/dsf/34/sdfs.tar.gz
```

Comment: is line 9 in the output a typo, missing the leading slash?

Comment: are you assuming that file paths don't contain any spaces? e.g. `/asdds/ads/adss/sdf.jpg asljdascuashn sdkm /sdf/dsf/dsf/dfs/sdfs.txt` could be one path with a directory named `sdf.jpg asljdascuashn sdkm ` in it

Comment: How do you know "dslkjcblasdjncklasdnlc" is not a path but  "/asdds/ads/adss/sdf.jpg" is? The former is a valid filename. What about if the file contains "foo/bar" -- do you want to accept that relative path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU grep's `-o` option, and assuming that file paths are split on spaces:

```
grep -o '/[^ ]*' < input
```